# Flatten RDD[(String,Map[String,Int])] to RDD[String,String,Int]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to flatten an RDD[(String,Map[String,Int])] to  RDD[String,String,Int] and ultimately save it as a dataframe.

```
    val rdd=hashedContent.map(f=>(f._1,f._2.flatMap(x=> (x._1, x._2))))
    val rdd=hashedContent.map(f=>(f._1,f._2.flatMap(x=>x)))
```

All having type mismatch errors.
Any help on how to flatten structures like this one?
EDIT:

```
    hashedContent -- ("A", Map("acs"->2, "sdv"->2, "sfd"->1)),
                     ("B", Map("ass"->2, "fvv"->2, "ffd"->1)),
                      ("c", Map("dg"->2, "vd"->2, "dgr"->1))
```

Comment: please provide the test data and the value for hashedcontent

Comment: @Chandan Added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close:

```
rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y._1, y._2)))
   .toDF()
   .show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  A|acs|  2|
|  A|sdv|  2|
|  A|sfd|  1|
|  B|ass|  2|
|  B|fvv|  2|
|  B|ffd|  1|
|  c| dg|  2|
|  c| vd|  2|
|  c|dgr|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

**Data**

```
val data = Seq(("A", Map("acs"->2, "sdv"->2, "sfd"->1)),
               ("B", Map("ass"->2, "fvv"->2, "ffd"->1)),
               ("c", Map("dg"->2, "vd"->2, "dgr"->1)))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
```

Comment: I am getting error at .toDF() Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: try running `import sqlContext.implicits._` first, what Spark version you are on?

Answer (score 2):

For completeness: an alternative solution (which might be considered more readable) would be to first convert the `RDD` into a `DataFrame`, and then to transform its structure using `explode`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

rdd.toDF("c1", "map")
  .select($"c1", explode($"map"))
  .show(false)

// same result:
// +---+---+-----+
// |c1 |key|value|
// +---+---+-----+
// |A  |acs|2    |
// |A  |sdv|2    |
// |A  |sfd|1    |
// |B  |ass|2    |
// |B  |fvv|2    |
// |B  |ffd|1    |
// |c  |dg |2    |
// |c  |vd |2    |
// |c  |dgr|1    |
// +---+---+-----+
```